# Is there any FTP server library for iOS 5.0

Tags: iphone, ftp

I'm writing something to use the iPhone as a FTP server. I'm looking for any open source library to help me do that. Someone recommanded DiddyFtpServer ( http://code.google.com/p/diddyftpserver/ ) but this project has been removed from code.google.com. I also found ios-ftp-server at http://code.google.com/p/ios-ftp-server/ but it's 'test project' can't work on my computer.(I build it and click 'run',but nothing happen.)

Is there any other library can I use? Or can someone tell me how to use ios-ftp-server (I just need it run first.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`ConnectionKit` : FTP/SFTP/WebDAV etc. for Cocoa : https://github.com/karelia/ConnectionKit
This is really amazing and very recommended .

Comment: And please go here http://www.matthew-long.com/2007/11/24/cocoaobjective-c-ftp-libraryframework/ and grab the ready example written by `Matt Long`

Comment: It looks like something for Mac and I can't run it as well (missing some farmeworks). However, I need a more simple one for iPhone.